# bash: id: command not found -bash: [: : integer expression expected

Tags: linux, debian

I am using Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). I am able to login remotely via ssh. I noticed after giving my credentials it shows both for user and root

```
Password:
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
root@debian:~#
```

I didn't find any solution regarding this problem. Do you have have any suggestion why I received it?

Comment: This has to be in one of the scripts that are executed by your bash when you log in. Does the same happen if you start `bash` from bash? What if you run `bash --login`?

Comment: Did you set up anything that modified `/etc/profile` on the server side, maybe? Do you happen to have a `~/.ssh/environment` on the local side?

Comment: @Marcus Müller I didn't check your first question yet. I also didn't write anything directly in the etc/profile. Yesterday, I just install jdk17 and set environment path in /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1" 
After that it appears. Anyway, I will go deep to it.

Comment: please **edit** your question to include what *exactly* you did. the way you wrote that looks broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to be in one of the scripts that are executed by your bash when you log in.

Barring the time to debug this with you, let's just look into what this could be:

`man bash` tells us these commands have to be in

- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bashrc`
- or a file defined by the environment variable `BASH_ENV`

or of course, any file loaded by any of these.

So, that's all we need to check. Check whether the environment variable is set (`echo "value: ${BASH_ENV}`) after logging in.

Since it shows for multiple users, the prime suspect is `/etc/profile`; I've not seen a broken one in ages (all things potentially modifying that go through lengths to be safe to run in different shells that might read it).

Your comment looks like your `PATH` entry in your `/etc/environment` might be broken, so that your system can't find executables.

Comment: I removed the PATH entry from /etc/environment and now the error has gone. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> Yesterday, I just install jdk17 and set environment path in /etc/environment PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1/bin" JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1" After that it appears.

Setting `PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1/bin"` results in a PATH that contains that directory *only*. `id` or any other commands won't be in the PATH after that. If one of the startup files contains something like this:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then ...
```

the command `id` would not be found, and the output of the command substitution would be the empty string, leading to the error.

You probably meant something like

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1/bin"
```

to *add* that directory to the PATH, but you *can't* do that in `/etc/environment` as it's not a shell script. Put the assignment in your `.bash_profile` or some other such place.